# Prove If $a_0=2, a_{n}=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}t^n(1-t)^n\sin( \pi t)dt(n\geq 1)$ then $a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=\frac{4n+2}{\pi}a_n $

Tags: recurrence-relations

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Please explain how to do this proof ? 
$$$$
If
$$a_0=2, a_{n}=\frac{\pi^{n+1}}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}t^n(1-t)^n\sin( \pi t)dt(n\geq 1)~~~$$
then 
$$a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}=\frac{4n+2}{\pi}a_n .$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try integration by parts twice.

Comment: Can the OP use the Beta unction here? Is it applicable here.

Comment: @BabakS. I might be mistaken, but I don't think you need the Beta function here.